# Logback not writing to new file after rolling

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I've created a logback on our project and use the org.slf4j.LoggerFactory and org.slf4j.Logger library. But we are still facing a problem in rollover since we started to use it. The problem is, after the rollover of the log file, instead of saving the logs in the new created file it saves the logs in the rolled over file. Below is my logback.xml configuration. For example, instead of logging into proj.log it will log to proj.2015-05-25.log. Any suggestion to fix this issue?

```
<file>/home/proj/proj-conf/logs/proj.log</file>
<encoder>
  <pattern>%d %-5p %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
</encoder>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
  <!-- daily rollover -->
    <fileNamePattern>/home/proj/proj-conf/logs/proj.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>

  <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
  <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
```

##

Comment: Ever find a solution to this issue? I just found out I have it too in production. Any help is appreciated!